# How to implement contact and collision only on one side of enemy in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection

Let's say I have a ball that rolls and jumps and a square blocks on the same line. I want this ball to collide only with the left side of a block. If ball is jumping over the block - they should not contact, ball shouldn't land on top of the square, it should just fall on a ground and roll further. I have this code:

```
self.ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.ball.size.width / 2))
self.ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
self.ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Square.rawValue
self.ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Square.rawValue

self.square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:square.texture, size: self.square.size)
self.square.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Square.rawValue
self.square.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
self.square.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
```

It's working well, but ball is colliding with the whole square. How can I change this using Swift in order to make what I want?

Comment: Are you asking to have this translated into Swift?

Comment: No, this is already in swift. I'm asking to help me to make only one side of a SKSpritenode available for collisions and contacts. This code is just how I made physicsBodies of my sprites. I thought it could help. I just wrote about swift because I don't know Obj-C and wouldn't be able to understand the answer if it would be in objective-c

Comment: @TimurTest I think you'll need to keep track of the balls position and conditionally set and remove the collision category for the item you want to conditionally collide with.